# Alguien sabe como mover un item a la parte final del div?

Tags: css, html5

soy yo de nuevo jajajaja, tengo un pequeno problema, hice un div y puse mis datos por asi decirlo, quiero poner un boton abajo a la derecha probe con `float: right;` pero me lo posiciona antes en la parte roja, yo lo quiero posicionar en la parte verde, pero no se si tengo que usar algun flex o algo...

```css
.section {
  background-color: blue;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  min-width: 1521px;
  padding: 5rem 13%;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

h1 {
  color: rgb(235, 231, 231);
}

.avatar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.perfil {
  color: rgb(235, 231, 231);
  font-size: 1.7rem;
}

.separator {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.2rem;
  max-width: 8rem;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  background-color: rgb(235, 231, 231);
}

.separator-icon {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  color: black;
}

.separator-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.followers-post {
  display: flex;
  color: rgb(235, 231, 231);
  margin-top: 5rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btn-header {
  float: right;
  border: none;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="section">

  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/bearded-happy-looking-man-with-brunette-hair-has-piercing-wearing-black-sweater-holding-pointing-finger-smartphone-copy-space-isolated-yellow-wall_295783-14549.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar" />

  <h1>Elvis Vera</h1>

  <div class="separator-container">
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <i class="fas fa-star separator-icon"></i>
    <div class="separator"></div>
  </div>

  <p class="perfil">15 años - Caracas - Venezuela</p>

  <div class="followers-post">
    <h5 class="followers">Seguidores 93k</h3>
      <h5 class="follows">Seguidos 100</h3>
        <h5 class="post"> Publicaciones 4 </h3>
  </div>

  <button class="btn-header"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
</header>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que has puesto un padding de 13% al contenedor de ese botón... para ponerlo pegado a la derecha deberás tener en cuenta ese padding (la mitad de él, de hecho)... por ejemplo, podrías ponerle `margin-right: -5%;` y eso lo moverá un 5% a la derecha, dejándolo más o menos en la posición que quieres, creo. Lo que yo habría hecho es no poner el padding al `.section`, si no crear un div dentro de él, que sería el encargado de tener ese padding, y el botón podría ir fuera del padding, quedando perfectamente alineado sin problemas :)

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, me ha funcionado a la perfeccion!!!